# I have a value 10000,1 in a xml and need to transform it to 10000,10 using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<Test>10000,1</Test>
```

What I have already done so far:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<Test><xsl:value-of select="format-number(Test, '0,00')"/></Test>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <Test><xsl:value-of select="format-number(Test, '#,##')"/></Test>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>`

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <Test><xsl:value-of select="Test"/></Test>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>`
```

When I use just the value-of select, I get as answer:
10000.1

When I try these other examples, what I get as answer is:
1,00,00

I want to get this as answer:
10000,10

Comment: One example does not constitute a specification. What output would you want if the input were, say, `10000,123` or `10000,0` or `10000` or `,123` or `100.00` or `1,000.00`? In short, what are the general rules?

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

First, the value of `10000,1` is not number; you need to change the comma to a period. Next, you cannot use a comma as a decimal separator in the `format-number` function unless you define it as such. Try it along the lines of:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:decimal-format name="eur" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Test>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(translate(Test, ',', '.'), '0,00', 'eur')"/>
    </Test>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine after adding this decilma format and the translation